# Problems with contact form and input validation

Tags: php, forms, validation

Ok so I am trying to create a contact form that validates user input to keep hackers from submitting codes and trying to require number, text, and email only. I have already styled the form and imported my php file. The contact from will send it to my gmail account. but everytime I test the php It allows for any type of data to be entered no matter if it is supposed to be a number and letters are submitted and the other way around. If I could get some help in telling me where I went wrong that would be great. I am a beginner at programming and only have the knowledge I recieved from school but I'm pretty good at html and css but having problems with the php validation. The form sends the email but like I said it allows any and all input.

```
    <?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: www.webdesignheros.com';
$to = 'heenanwrk@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Service Email for HeenanTech';
    $tel = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'tel', FILTER_SANITIZE_INT);
    $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING|FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    $message = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'message', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING|FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);

$body = "From: $name\n Phone: $tel\n Email: $email\n Message: $message\n";
?>

<?php
if ($_POST['submit']){
    if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $from)){
    echo'<p>Thank you for your email!</p>';
    } else {
    echo '<p> Oops! Something went wrong, try sending your message again</p>';
    }
}

?>
```

Additionally the form can be found at [http://webdesignheros.com/Contact.html][1]

[1]: http://webdesignheros.com/Contact.html and if someone could tell me how to reject certain input before the submit that would be awesome too. like if an invalid entry was input and they move on to the next input it would reject it and not let the submit button be pushed. would i use the `pattern="a-z"` in the html or would i need to add javascript for that?

Comment: What exactly is not working here ? Is that all the code you have or is there more than this ?

Comment: Do you have client validation? (javascript, f.e. jquery-validate - http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Comment: 1) I don't think there is any FILTER_SANITIZE_INT, but there is FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT. 2) Numbers are considered strings when they are with letters. For example: "My123" is a valid string.

Comment: this is all the code i have in php. all i was wanting was it to send to my gmail account so i didnt think i need javascript. and yes i did type in the FILTER_SANITIZE wrong and i fixed it an now it filters out the letters but i dont want it to send if the wrong input is added. the thing that isnt working is that the name is string but i dont want the special characters in it and the tel is allowing letters with the numbers.

Answer (score 2):

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit")){
 $name = $_POST["name"];
    $tel = $_POST["tel"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];
    $from = "From: www.webdesignheros.com";
    $to = "heenanwrk@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Service Email for HeenanTech";
    $body = "From: $name\n Phone: $tel\n Email: $email\n Message: $message\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $body, $from);

        if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $from)){
        echo'<p>Thank you for your email!</p>';
        } else {
        echo '<p> Oops! Something went wrong, try sending your message again</p>';
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you that worked great. I forgot about the 'isset' if statement! that got it to remove the special characters.